# Start a computer from another computer using PowerShell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I need to Start a computer from another machine's PowerShell console. But I am not able to find suitable PowerShell v2 command to do it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`restart-computer` is the cmdlet to use. You need to have the permissions to remote restart a computer though. Read more about this [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849837.aspx)

Comment: That will not work when the computer is powered off. The question was how to start a computer remotely when its power is off

Comment: I still can't find the powered off condition in the question. BTW, I don't think one can access a remote machine  any which way if it is turned off.

Comment: He said start, not restart. This implies he is looking to power the computer on from an offline state. And yes, there is no way to access the machine if it is powered off.

Comment: What about "Wake On LAN" then? It could power on a computer that is turned off.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to start a physical computer remotely if it is powered off.  I assume this is what you are trying to do, since you asked how to start the computer as opposed to restarting it.

Comment: What about "Wake On LAN" then? It could power on a computer that is turned off.

Comment: ^This, sending the correct (magic) packet to the router should work